# Verify this matlab code

Tags: matlab

I want to plot the fractal generated by the functions:

```
    x(k+1)=y(k)(1+sin(0.7x(k))-1.2+sqrt(|x|))
    y(k+1)=0.21-x(k)
```

with the initial conditions y(0)=x(0)=0, then I did the following code.

```
x=zeros(100);
y=zeros(100);
x(1)=0;
y(1)=0;

for k=1:100
 x(k+2)=y(k+1)(1+sin(0.7x(k+1))-1.2+sqrt(abs(x+1)))
 y(k+2)=0.21-x(k+1)
end
plot(x,y,'.')
```

So, Am I right?, or How can I fix it if I am wrong?, Well the thing is that I want to have a fractal,but I have run this out and it gave me only isolated points, the requirement is not to join them, therefore I want to know of this code has the right sintaxis and I it works well, so the thing is that if it is doing the right thing ;)

Thanks a lot for your help.

### Edition

```
x=zeros(100);
y=zeros(100);
x(1)=0;
y(1)=0;

for k=0:100
 x(k+2)=y(k+1)*(1+sin(0.7*x(k+1))-1.2*sqrt(abs(x(k+1))));
 y(k+2)=0.21-x(k+1);
end
plot(x,y,'.')
```

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88335/discussion-on-question-by-user162343-verify-this-matlab-code).

Answer (score 2):

Using the code you provided, I added the line `print("MyPNG.png", "-dpng")` and ran the code from [Saturn Fiddle](https://saturnapi.com/vpartition/generating-fractals/edit).

```
x=zeros(100);
y=zeros(100);
x(1)=0;
y(1)=0;

for k=0:100
 x(k+2)=y(k+1)*(1+sin(0.7*x(k+1))-1.2*sqrt(abs(x(k+1))));
 y(k+2)=0.21-x(k+1);
end
plot(x,y,'.')
print("MyPNG.png", "-dpng")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :), and I think this code is correct, isnt?